# Is there a way to determine the URL of a Google form's edit page from that form's view page?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

The address of a Google form's edit page is in the form of https://docs.google.com/forms/d/[LONG_ID]/edit while the view/data entry address is in the form https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/[DIFFERENT_LONG_ID]/viewform

Is it possible (via an API or other means) to get the edit URL from the view URL? I ask as the Google Apps Script FormApp has a function to get a form from a URL, but it only seems to work using the edit URL (and the corresponding get by ID function only works with the ID of the edit page, not the ID of the view page).

Also, are there any Google Form URL formats/patterns that I've missed?